# 'Cannot read properties of undefined events' Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <FullCalendar id="calendar"
  :options="calendarOptions"
  />
</section>
```

---

```
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  },
  
  
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin ,interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
```

---

```
  methods:{
    newEvent(){
      var theCalendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
      var eventName = document.getElementById("Ename").value;
      var sDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
      var eDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
      var type = document.getElementById("bookingType").value;
      var number = document.getElementById("numberOfPeople").value;
      
      //The addEvent can't be accessed, currently this function doesn't have access to the object Fullcalendar and because of that
      //we can't use addEvent.
        theCalendar.addEvent({
        title: eventName,
        start: sDate,
        allDay: true
      });
      alert('Great. Now, update your database...');

    }
  }
```

Hello, my vue.JS code at the moment cant read undefined properties. I want to be able to populate the addEvent class with my calendar properties.

Comment: that is a very none vue approach you have taken, normally you would bind the input to a variable and then read the data from that variable, and if you do need to directly access the dom you should use a ref https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html

Comment: I have added a reference to the calendar in the template, and in the function, I have called the reference (this.$refs.calendar.addEvent) but that didn't seem to work (same error).

Comment: looks like you missed the `.getApi()` call ie `this.$refs.calendar.getApi().addEvent()` assuming `addEvent` is actually on the api

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access the API

you should provide a ref on your calendar

```
<FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar" :options="calendarOptions" />
```

which can then be accessed as so

```
let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()
calendarApi.next()
```

see [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue)

however i suspect that you actually want is to access the calendarOptions object which is as simple as

```
this.calendarOptions.events
```

assuming you have defined the object as specified on the previous link

```
data() {
  return {
    calendarOptions: {
      plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
      events: [
        { title: 'event 1', date: '2019-04-01' },
        { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-04-02' }
      ]
    }
  }
},
```